# Mysql losing 11 records on insert

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I download an XML file containing 1048 records, and then I successfully create a table($today) in my DB, and load the XML data into the MySQL table.

I then run a second script which contains this query:

```
INSERT INTO
        t1
(
    modelNumber,
    salePrice

    )
SELECT modelNumber,salePrice
FROM `'.$today.'`

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE t1.modelNumber=`'.$today.'`.modelNumber,
 t1.salePrice=`'.$today.'`.salePrice
");
```

It works, but I'm losing 11 records. The total count is 1037, while the $today table has the exact amount of records contained in the XML file (1048).

How can I correct this problem?

Comment: Runs some queries on the $today to find your 11 duplicates..

Comment: This could have any number of reasons. Add some debug outputs to the script you're using to parse the XML file with to find out what the problem is.

Comment: It looks like the original XML file contains duplicates, as I just ran a query on $table and it showed me 1047 distinct records.

Comment: @gbn Please put your comment in an answer so I can accept, as your comment addressed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runs some queries on the $today to find your 11 duplicates.

The ON DUPLICATE KEY clause will suppress these 11 records.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a duplicate key in your file, you update the old row

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Means that if the `insert` doesn't work because of a duplicate key, you get the `update` mentioned after that line.

There are probably 11 entries that are duplicate keys, and they `update` rather then `insert`. I would change it to this (a bit of a hack, but the quickest way I can think without any more info to find the culprints)

```
INSERT INTO
        t1
(
    modelNumber,
    salePrice

    )
SELECT modelNumber,salePrice
FROM `'.$today.'`

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE t1.modelNumber=`'.$today.'`.modelNumber,
 t1.salePrice= '999999999'
");
```

Then you can look for entries with that salePrice fo 9999999 , and you at least know what (or even if) duplicate keys you need to look for in your XML